# HTML5 Websocket sending simultaneous data to server

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Can I send simultaneous data to server in html5 websockets?

For example :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    conn = {}, window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;     
    connection1();
});

function connection1() {
    // uses global 'conn' object
    if (conn.readyState === undefined || conn.readyState > 1) {
        conn1 = new WebSocket('ws://ip1:8101');

        //connection open 
        conn1.onopen = function () {
            conn1.send("Connection1 Established Confirmation");
        }
    };

    conn1.onmessage = function(message){
        conn1.send("data1");
        conn1.send("data2");
        conn1.send("data3");
        conn1.send("data4");
    };
}
```

data1,data2,data3,data4 needs to be send to server at a time.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Web socket sends are always asynchronous. When you call send four times, these will be sent immediately and the program will continue without waiting for an acknowledgment from the server.

They will, however, reach the server as separate messages. When you want one message `data1data2data3data4`, you have to do this in one send.

Comment: The question was if several big messages will be sent in parallel or queued for send. It doesn't matter if API is asynchronous or not.